# Loop over whole array starting from any index

Tags: c++, c++11, template

I recently had to repeatedly iterate over an array but increment the index to start from each time. Since this is quite cumbersome in comparison to a normal for loop I made a small template function that does this for me:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename TSize, typename TFunc>
void for_start(const TSize start, const TSize size, TFunc&& fn)
{
    for(TSize c{}, i{c + start}; c < size; ++c, ++i)
    {
        if(i >= size)
            i = 0;
        fn(i);
    }
}

template<typename TRAIter, typename TFunc>
void for_start(TRAIter start, TRAIter begin, TRAIter end, TFunc&& fn)
{
    for(TRAIter c{begin}, i{c + std::distance(begin, start)}; c != end; ++i, ++c)
    {
        if(i == end)
            i = begin;

        fn(i);
    }
}

// usage
int main()
{
    const unsigned ARR_SIZE{10};
    int arr[ARR_SIZE]{
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    };


    for_start(5u, ARR_SIZE, [arr](unsigned i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    });
    std::cout << '\n';

    for_start(std::begin(arr) + 5, std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](const int* i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    });
}

// prints:
// 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 
// 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
```

I'd like to get some feedback on things like usability (function name, order of parameters) and reuseability. Note that I'd like to use this function with signed & unsigned integers.

Comment: If you weren't constrained to C++11, I'd have suggested you look into `std::range`, which has been voted in to C++20.

Comment: @TobySpeight, this is not my birthday, but thank you for the gift. Though googling for it didn't yield anything useful yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is no reason to initialize `i` as `{c + std::distance(begin, start)}`. Upon such initialization you are guaranteed that `i == start`. A much simpler `i{start}` suffices.
- Testing for `i == size`, or `i == end` inside the loop, as well as tracking two iterators, feels wasteful. Consider splitting the loop into two, e.g:

  ```
      for (i = start; i != end; ++i) {
          fn(i);
      }

      for (i = begin; i != start; ++i) {
          fn(i);
      }
  ```
- I am not sure that `for_start` is a good name. I am also not sure what name would be good. `iterate_rotated` perhaps?

Comment: The idea to use 2 seperate loops didn't even cross my mind... Thank you!